# How to determine the first row after which a variable continuously decreases?

Tags: r

### Problem

Given the following dataset, I want to find the first row after which `vn` continuously decreases (highlighted with a red circle). I know `which` can be used, but I don't know how to ensure a continuous decrease. Please guide me.

[image]

### Data

```
df <- structure(list(Time = c(152.216666666667, 152.233333333333, 152.25, 
152.266666666667, 152.283333333333, 152.3, 152.316666666667, 
152.333333333333, 152.35, 152.366666666667, 152.383333333333), 
    vn = c(22.8733019569441, 22.8485877814354, 22.8539833863057, 
    22.8293883815954, 22.8347839864658, 22.8101348273251, 22.8047392224548, 
    22.7798917511031, 22.7744961462328, 22.7496737884944, 22.7442781836241
    ), diff_vn = c(0.00539560487035118, -0.024714175508727, 0.00539560487035118, 
    -0.0245950047103243, 0.00539560487035118, -0.0246491591406404, 
    -0.00539560487035118, -0.0248474713516487, -0.00539560487035118, 
    -0.0248223577383548, -0.00539560487035118), sign_diff_vn = c(1, 
    -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: When you say continously decreases,  suppose you have `c(1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1)` what would be the output

Comment: The output for that example should be `NA`. I can use the criteria that sign is `-1` for 10 times in a row. Thanks for asking this question.

Comment: So you meant `-1` till the last row should be the counted one?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Thanks.

Comment: Then, please check the solutionss below.  I think the `rleid` one should be bug free

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `diff`

```
 with(df, which(c(diff(sign_diff_vn) == 0, FALSE))[1])
[1] 6
```

Or may also be

```
v1 <- cumsum(df$sign_diff_vn >=0)
 match(max(v1), v1) + 1
[1] 6
```

---

Or another option is `rleid`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number(), grp = rleid(sign_diff_vn)) %>% 
    filter(grp == max(grp) & sign_diff_vn < 0) %>% 
    pull(rn) %>%
    first
[1] 6
```

Comment: Love the `diff` approach!